# Explicit use of `self` in method name in class definition

Tags: ruby, self, class-eval

This code is from the Rails Crash Course book:

```
class Accessor
  def self.accessor(attr)
    class_eval "
      def #{attr}
        @#{attr}
      end

      def #{attr}=(val)
        @#{attr} = val
      end
    "
  end
end
```

The idea is that a subclass of `Accessor` can create getter and setter methods by calling the `accessor` method with the attribute name for which we wish to generate getter and setter methods:

```
class Element < Accessor
  accessor :name
...
```

But, why the use of `self` in `def self.accessor(attr)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to define accessors for all instances of a class; you don't want to define them for certain instances and not define them for other instances. Hence, defining accessors is something you want to do against a class, not an instance; thus `accessor` has to be a class method, not an instance method. It will be called in the class body when used.

Comment: Indeed! I come from Java and python, and I forgot the syntax to define class methods. Thank you.